# Contour integration of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Given a meromorphic function $f$ which is uniformly bounded on the upper half plane. Assume that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)dx$ is absolutely integrable. Then Cauchy's integral theorem suggests $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=0$ except there is some tricky business around infinity. Can someone give me a counterexample or a supporting argument?

Comment: I'm not a complex analysis expert, but should you take the closed contour consisting of the half circle counterclockwise, what the residue theorem tells you is that $$\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} f(x) \, dx + \int_{C_R} f(z) \, dz = 0,$$ and that does not necessarily imply that $\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} f(x) \, dx = 0$. Again, not a complex analysis expert.

Comment: The two assumptions that I add, (1)the integral is integrable and (2)$f$ is uniformly bounded on the upper half plane, are to encourage good decay of $f(z)$ as $z$ go to infinity in the upper half plane, which may suggest that the integration on the half circle decay.

Comment: So these two conditions ensure Jordan's Lemma? I'm not too familiar with contour integration and your question looks interesting, looking forward to answers.

Comment: Your function is a suspicious object. Study $z\mapsto f(1/z)$.

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla Could you be more precise? $\frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2}$ is such a function.

Comment: Isn't entire, has poles.

Comment: So entire functions cannot be absolutely integrable along the real line. What about meromorphic functions?

Comment: Entire functions can be absolutely integrable along the real line, take $e^{-z^2}$ for an example. (That is not bounded on the upper half plane, though, so doesn't concern your question, only your last comment.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded on the upper half-plane, it has no poles there or on the real axis.

For $\varepsilon > 0$, consider the functions

$$g_\varepsilon(z) = \frac{f(z)}{1 - i\varepsilon z},\quad h_\varepsilon(z) = g_\varepsilon(z)\cdot e^{i\varepsilon z}.$$

$g_\varepsilon(z)$ satisfies the same assumptions as $f$, and additionally, we have $g_\varepsilon(z) \to 0$ for $z\to\infty$ in the upper half plane (or on the real axis). By Jordan's lemma,

$$\int_{\gamma_R} h_\varepsilon(z)\,dz \xrightarrow{R\to+\infty} 0,$$

where $\gamma_R$ is the semicircle with radius $R$ and centre $0$ in the upper half plane. By Cauchy's integral theorem, we deduce

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_{\varepsilon}(x)\,dx = 0.$$

By the dominated convergence theorem (we have $\lvert h_\varepsilon(z)\rvert \leqslant \lvert f(z)\rvert$), we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \lim_{\varepsilon\searrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty h_\varepsilon(x)\,dx = 0.$$

Comment: Do you know some concrete example of such function?

Comment: Only boring ones. $\frac{1}{(z+i)^2}$, more generally any rational function that has poles only in the lower half plane, a zero at $\infty$, and sum of residues $0$. You can multiply such a function with anything that is bounded on the upper half plane. I suspect that a function satisfying the conditions must actually have $f(z)\to 0$ as $z\to \infty$ in $\{z : \operatorname{Im} z \geqslant 0\}$, and then the factor $\frac{1}{1-i\varepsilon z}$ is not needed, but I'm not sure about that, and don't see how to prove it if true.

Comment: Thanks. But my skepticism was about the original hypotesis (entire).

Comment: If we require $f$ entire, the only example I can offer is the truly trivial one. I can't prove it's the only one, however.